# Induction step other than $1$

Tags: logic, induction, examples-counterexamples

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. I'm trying to prove that the following implication is true only when $k=1$:
$$[\exists n_0 \ \ \ P(n_0)] \land[\forall n\ge n_0 \ \ \ P(n) \implies P(n+k)] \implies [\forall n\ge n_0 \ \ \ P(n) ]$$
Obviously in the case $k=1$ we have the axiom of induction. How can we construct counterexamples for the other cases $k\not = 1$? Is it possible to give only one counterexample which works for all $k\not = 1$?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Do you mean it works for all $k$?

Comment: The axiom holds assuming the "next number" property. If you skip one it does not.

Comment: Try with "n is Even". $P(2)$ holds so we have $n_0=2$ and it holds with $k=2$ but not every number is Even.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Okay, that works for even $k$. What about odd $k$?

Comment: Not clear... Obviously, we can manufacture a counter-example with $k=3$, but having found one, it is enough to show that it does not hold for $k > 1$. Consider $n_0=3$ an add 3 to "prove" that every number is a multiple of 3.

Comment: Obviously we can fix it, using as $P(k)$ the property "2k is Even", We have that $P(2)$ holds and if $P(2k)$ holds, than also $P(2(k+1))$ holds. But is only a contrieved way to use the axiom.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I see. I think the given answer covers all the cases. Do you agree with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your $k, n_0$ and let $P(n)$ be true iff $n \equiv n_0 \pmod{k}$. Then $P(n) \implies P(n+k)$, but $P(n)$ is only true for all $n \geq n_0$ if $k=1$.